# Is $\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ irrational where $\gcd(a_i,b_i) = 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_i$, $b_i$, $i=0,\ldots,\infty$, are two integer sequences with $\gcd(a_i,b_i)=1$ for all $i$.

Is then the limit $\frac{a_\infty}{b\infty}$ irrational if not $\frac{a_\infty}{b\infty}=\frac{A}{B}$ for some $\gcd(A,B)=1$  (assuming the limit exists at all)?

Comment: I think this can't quite be what you're asking? It looks like you're asking, "if the limit exists at all, is it irrational if it's not rational?" (See Zev Chonoles' answer.)

Comment: You *could* get an irrational limit, for example consecutive Fibonacci numbers ($a_n=b_{n+1}=\frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\phi-\psi}$ for $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$, $\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2$) approaching the golden mean, but there are way too many possible such sequences to make such a statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - for example, let $a_i=2$ and $b_i=3$ for all $i$. Then $\gcd(a_i,b_i)=\gcd(2,3)=1$ and 
$$\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{a_i}{b_i}=\frac{2}{3}$$
is rational.

---

Your question, as edited, is trivially true because any rational number can be expressed as $\frac{A}{B}$ where $\gcd(A,B)=1$; so if the limit cannot be expressed that way, it will be irrational. That the number occurs as a limit of anything is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

No. For example $(n+1)/n \to 1$, and $\operatorname{pgcd}(n+1,n)=1$.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance: what is a $pgcd$? I know $gcd$, but I have not heard of $pgcd$.

Comment: PGCD (*plus grand commun diviseur*) is French for GCD (*greatest common divisor*).